# A question about a management property

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to create a People Directory. What is the reason i do not have the field Department when i click Selected Properties of the PnP Search Result webpart ?

Gr. P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that all the properties come from the properties that are managed with the Search. Please navigate to SharePoint Admin Center>More features >Search >Manage Search Schema. Please check if you have this department property.

[image]

If this property is present, I suggest you configure the PnP search result in the other site's page to see if the problem still exists.